# Install a "base system" only and add only wanted packages after

Tags: mac, ubuntu-minimal

I used to have Ubuntu, but I stopped using since in each release almost everything changes, default applications are changed and such.

I'm with a mac I'm planning to install along with Mac OS X. I would like to install just a base system, but having the ubuntu package manager and the repositories, even without gnome, and install using the command line, but with the Mac drivers (for example, multi-touch and webcam). Anyone knows a guide for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Minimal CD Image for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)
2. [Ubuntu-Wiki LowMemorySystems Installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems)
3. [Google Knol Minimal Desktop Installation Guide](http://knol.google.com/k/ubuntu-minimal-desktop-installation-guide#)

The minimal CD image will give just the command-line operating system, which allows you to install all the needed packages to run the graphical-X system.  Following either/both of the guides you can pick and choose exactly what you want to be included in your new system. After that, you can login into the base OS and run your preferred package manager (Synaptic, Muon, etc...) to add the extra packages from available repositories and ppa.

Comment: Number 1 on the list is a must... that is the link to obtain the Minimal CD Image... Link 2 and 3 shows you how to configure your machine after a minimal install.

Comment: The link under 3. is not valid anymore

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're not setting up a server you can achieve this by installing [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download) and choosing not to install any additional packages during the installation. This will give a fairly minimal system.